# For loop goes into infinite loop when I use a variable as ending condition

Tags: loops, for-loop, verilog, quartus

I have a for loop that runs fine in Verilog.  It looks like this:

```vhdl
for(j=0; j<=5; j=j+1)begin
    ...
end
```

but as soon as I change the 5 into a variable:

```vhdl
for(j=0; j<=m; j=j+1)begin
    ...
end
```

I get this error:

> [Error (10119)](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd04232012_554.html): Verilog HDL Loop Statement error at alu.v(95): loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within 250 iterations

I have m as a reg initialized as such:

```vhdl
reg [3:0] m = 5;
```

The reason I need to use a variable is I have an another variable that I want this loop to count to. I was getting the same error so I used this test value 'm' that should always equal 5.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  I would think the loop would end after 5, but for some reason it doesn't.  Please help!

Comment: Are you implementing (looking) for synthesise or non-synthesise stuff?

Comment: This is synthesis, since the "[Error (10119)](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd04232012_554.html)" is generated by Altera Quartus II/Prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog HDL is not programming language, like e.g. C or Python, but a Hardware Description Language (HDL).  So the synthesis tool will unroll the `for` loop to a fixed hardware circuit, and for this it needs to know the (maximum) number of iterations in the loop.

In your case it appears that the synthesis tool (Altera Quartus II/Prime), can't figure this out when the end condition is based on `m` as a register, so you have to rewrite this to each loop has a constant end condition, allowing the synthesis tool to unroll this to a fixed hardware circuit.